# creating simple sounds on pygame

Tags: python, audio, pygame, midi

I've been trying to get simple beep sounds on pygame but couldn't find exactly how to do it. I know I need to create a sound array object and feed it to `pygame.sndarray.make_sound(array)` but how do I make this array exactly and how do I play it?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't personally played around with SoundArray in PyGame, but I found some tutorials which should be able to get you started.

http://lists.canonical.org/pipermail/kragen-hacks/2007-November/000465.html
http://web.media.mit.edu/~nvawter/otherProduct/explanation%20Part%20I.html